# Detecting bad information (python/pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to python and pandas and I was wondering if I am able to have pandas filter out information within a dataframe that is otherwise inconsistent. For example, imagine that I have a dataframe with 2 columns, (1) product code and (2) unit of measurement. The same product code in column 1 may repeat several times and there would be several different product codes, I would like to filter out the product codes for which there is more than 1 unit of measurement for the same product code. Ideally, when this happen the filter would bring all instances of such product code, not just the instance in which the unit of measurement is different. To put more color to my request, the real objective here is to identify the product codes which have inconsistent unit of measurements, as the same product code should always have the same unit of measurement in all instances.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Give your input dataframe and expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you want some mapping of product code -> unit of measurement, ie the ground truth. You can either upload this, or try to be clever and derive it from the data assuming that the most frequently used unit of measurement for product code is the correct one. You could get this by doing

```
truth_mapping = df.groupby(['product_code'])['unit_of_measurement'].agg(lambda x:x.value_counts().index[0]).to_dict()
```

Then you can get a column that is the 'correct' unit of measurement

```
df['correct_unit'] = df['product_code'].apply(truth_mapping.get)
```

Then you can filter to rows that do not have the correct mapping:

```
df[df['correct_unit'] != df['unit_of_measurement']]
```

Comment: Thanks for the extremely fast reply!!! I will play around with this and see if I can pull it off. Will let you how this develops!

Comment: Update! it works better than I had imagined, i can do lots with this! Thank you again!

Comment: hcmw, I am having an issue implementing this to my real code... getting keyerror: “product_code”. Any thoughts ? This had worked on my mock code... I may be missing something.

Comment: i would guess you don't have a column named 'product_name', it is probably named something slightly different or is the index. if you do `df.columns` you should be able to list all your columns

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Sample df:

```
df12= pd.DataFrame({'Product Code':['A','A','A','A','B','B','C','C','D','E'],
                   'Unit of Measurement':['x','x','y','z','w','w','q','r','a','c']})
```

Group by and see count of all non unique pairs:

```
new = df12.groupby(['Product Code','Unit of Measurement']).size().reset_index().rename(columns={0:'count'})
```

Drop all rows where the Product Code is repeated

```
new.drop_duplicates(subset=['Product Code'], keep=False)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Rahul! I will try your suggested solution and let you know soon! Cheers!

Comment: Rahul, I tried the above, and the 2 first lines of code work to count the number of instances in which each code has a given UM. But the third line of the code does not change the output... am i missing something? At any rate, this is already useful and I have combined the 2 solutions provided for this question to have very useful results. Thanks !!

Comment: `new.drop_duplicates(subset=['Product Code'], keep=False)` if you mean this line, then this will delete all the rows where you have incorrect mapping. In above example rows where it has "A" and "C"

Comment: Rahul, I cant upvote due to my low reputation, since I joined literally yesterday. And i thought that the other answer was more useful for my request. So i accepted the other answer. Nonetheless, if I could accept both answers, I would! cheers!